# .net 4.5 application asking for .net 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have targeted the .net 4.5 framework for my application. when it is installed on a clients machine and they try to run and error pops up saying I need to download .net 4.0. After downloading .net 4.0 and trying to run the app again it shows an error saying I need .net 4.5.

Why does the app not just ask for 4.5 in the first place? This is the framework I have targeted.

Answer (score 2):

Because .NET 4.5 is an in-place update to .NET 4.0, not a standalone installation.  So you need 4.0 installed on the client machine first, before you can upgrade it to 4.5.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653